# Why are my roast potatoes not coming off crunchy?

Tags: potatoes, roasting

Besides the first time making them, they always come off with a soft,straight surface rather than a crunchy, craggy surface full of blisters.

Here is the [recipe](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2016/12/the-best-roast-potatoes-ever-recipe.html). The thing making the potatoes crunchy is a slurry (after parboiling the potatoes, you toss them with some oil. Their surface then gets ripped, making the slurry) that coats the surface. Here is a picture before cooking:
[image]

Here is a picture after cooking:
[image]

Its smooth and not crunchy. Any idea how to make them crunchy next time?

Comment: Are you using the same type of potatoes recommended in the recipe? Have you checked your oven temperature with a thermometer?

Comment: I'd let the potatoes dry out more before coating them with the oil; they should have a dry surface.

Comment: @Catija Yukon Golden is not available here in Israel

Comment: @Max You mean after parboiling yeah? Because the author only lets them sit for 30 seconds before tossing them in oil.

Comment: Then what did you use instead? The article attached to that recipe is **very** clear about which types of potato will give good results and which will not.

Comment: Yes, he's very specific about the the potato variety. I also use more oil than he calls for sometimes putting more on halfway if I don't like they way they are cooking. What oil do you use? I usually use olive oil, but have used some bacon drippings too with good results.

Comment: Steam is your enemy: enough room in pan and oven?

Comment: @SteveS. What more oil will do in terms of crunchiness?

Comment: @Catija I think winston potatoes or russet. I have no idea since they don't label them in Israeli supermarkets

Comment: @BarAkiva So the store will just write “potatoes” on the labels or do they give some indication of type? Either a name of a variety (like for apples), or something about the intended uses/dishes or, generic cooking properties?

Answer (score 2):

Your result looks like too much water, and too high a roasting temperature for an even, golden crust. (The ones illustrated in the recipe don't look as if they achieve that, either).

My way: Choose a floury, not a waxy, potato variety.

Par-boil from cold in salted water, until 3/4 cooked, a skewer should meet resistance before reaching the middle. (about 9-10 minutes, your size.). Drain in a colander, and leave to dry completely, but not cool.

Pre-heat your fat in the roasting tray, a thin layer. Transfer the potatoes to half-fill a dry bowl, pour over the hot fat, and shake gently to break up the surface. The roasting tray should be big enough to give the potatoes room to breathe, they shouldn't be crammed in.

Roast at about 180C (fan) for 40 minutes or so, turning once or twice. If your oven gets steamy, open the door a crack every now and then to let the steam out. Before serving, keep warm, uncovered, somewhere that doesn't trap steam, on paper towels to wick away excess fat.